# PayPal mc_gross format number?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working on an php ipn script. but i'm stuck on mc_gross check.

I store the amounts in database in this format (not number format):

```
1000
100
10000
```

How paypal send back to me the mc_gross value? in number format? i mean like this:

```
1,000
100
10,000
```

Coz if i store amounts in that format and paypal send the format back to me in number formats i'll have an not equal operation

```
1000 == 1,000 - false
```

So i need to verify if my stored amount si the same as mc_gross that paypal sends me back.

Comment: @Andy no, i m saying if i store this: 1000 and paypal send me 1,000.00 the function `if(1000 == 1,000.00)` will not give me true, but they really are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option:

```
if($my_val==  intval(str_replace(',', '', $pay_pal_val)){
//alll good
}
```